# Mongoose $gte Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose, momentjs

Why is mongo client returning an answer for the query and **Mongoose** is not.

```
db.dates.find({"date_out" : { $gte : ISODate("2018-11-12T00:00:00.000Z") }}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5be8a9eeda7bbc1fc40c1fa1"),
    "user" : "some.user@example.com",
    "date_in" : ISODate("2018-11-11T22:15:10.095Z"),
    "date_out" : ISODate("2018-11-14T22:00:00Z"),
    "userId" : "5be5a96e6db7be0568ea6e47"
 }
```

But when I try to do the same query in Mongoose it doesn't return anything

```
import Dates from "../models/Date";
import moment from 'moment';
const today = moment().startOf('day').toDate(); // 2018-11-11T22:00:00.000Z
const query = { date_out : { $gte : today }};

router.get("/unavailable", (req, res) => {
   Dates.find( query )
    .then(Booked_Dates => res.json({ Booked_Dates }))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ errors: parseErrors(err.errors) }));
});
```

Also tried `const query = { date_out : { $gte : 'ISODate("${today}")' }};`

' = `

Can you please point me in the right direction.

PS: If I take out the query it returns the proper result.

Also this is the schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: String, required: true },
  date_in: { type: String, required: true },
  date_out: { type: String, required: true },
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true }
});

export default mongoose.model("Date", schema);
```

Comment: how it worked for you.

Comment: I added your test data in mongo ... used a simple mongoose/nodejs app and queried the collection with your `query`. Got the expected result. Good luck.

Comment: Still not working for me. If I use the MONGO connector works as expected, when I use MONGOOSE it is not working...

Comment: The dates in MongoDB are **NOT** strings. They are BSON `Date` types when returned using `ISODate()` as a helper in the shell. So you're schema is casting values as "string" and then they do not match. Change the schema `date_out: { type: Date }` so it actually casts as a BSON Date.

Comment: I posted the exact same this the same time as @NeilLunn but since the updated answer now looks weird with the comments I will remove it.

Comment: @NeilLunn You are the best, thank you very much I have been struggling a lot with this I forgot I mocked some data and forgot String instead of Date.

Comment: @Akrion Well you can always flag the comments on your answer for deletion. I can't see any logical reason to reject the flags since the "context" is the answer is changed after the comments were made and the comments no longer refer to the new content and can be removed. Or, leave the original content for context and include the "edit". There likely is a duplicate issue, but I can't find one right now, so an answer is still valid.